# jQuery fadeIn function just appearing without fadeIn

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have a function that should produce a fadeIn, but it isn't. I am not sure if the parameters are correct and would appreciate some advice on where I have incorrectly coded. The code that is using the fadeIn, is this **$('#fb_message').fadeIn('slow', function() {**.

Is it something to do with the reset above it?

Many thanks.

```
$('#fb_submit').click(function () {

        var name = $('#fb_uname').val();
        var client = $('#fb_client').val();
        var department = $('#fb_department').val();
        var email = $('#fb_email').val();
        var position = $('#fb_position').val();
        var feedback = $('#fb_feedbacknew').val();
        var data = 'fb_uname=' + name +
                   '&fb_client=' + client +
                   '&fb_department=' + department +
                   '&fb_email=' + email +
                   '&fb_position=' + position +
                   '&fb_feedbacknew=' + feedback;
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "feedback.php",
            data: data,
            success: function (data) {
                $("#feedback").get(0).reset();
                $('#fb_message').fadeIn('slow', function() {

                    $('#fb_message').html(data);
                    });

                //$("#form").dialog('close');
                $("#flex1").flexReload();

            }
        });
        return false;

    });
```

Comment: Is `#fb_message` initially hidden? `fadeIn()` won't do anything if the animated element is already visible.

Comment: `$('#fb_message').hide()`, write this code somewhere and the try your code

Comment: I have put: <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript"> $('#fb_message').hide(); </script> on page where form is and changed 'slow' to 5000 and it waits 5 seconds then just appears. No fadeIn

Comment: @bollo, did you perchance disable animations by setting `$.fx.off` to `true` somewhere in your code?

Comment: @ Frédéric Hamidi No I did not. Do I have to? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

is your code in ????

```
$(document).ready(function){


});
```

try

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript"> 

    $(document).ready(function){

           $('#fb_message').hide(); 
    });
</script>
```

UPDATE

try this also in your success function

```
  success: function (data) {
        $("#feedback").get(0).reset();

        $('#fb_message').hide().html(data).fadeIn('slow');

        //$("#form").dialog('close');
        $("#flex1").flexReload();

    }
```

Comment: still the same. Is my function correct that I posted in my code? thanks

Comment: your edit kinda worked. It seems to sit at 50% opacity then jerkly jumps to 100%. I tried changing 'slow' to 5000 to try. If I leave on 'slow' it jumps straight in.